# Liquility wallet upgrade manifest v2 to v3 with es6 module

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am updating the manifest file from v2 to v3 but getting a error with background.js file . unable to load the node module

can you help me in this

I am unable to find any doc and any reference regarding this. can you share any reference

thanks